# howto stop apache matching /favicon with /favicon.ico

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache-config

I have site running with apache mod_rewrite and php

In my public_html folder i have diss .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)$ index.php?reurl=$1
```

this works fine if there are no files in that directory with the same name. so for example /favicon would match the file /favicon.ico and the RewriteRule would never be executed.

how can i stop /favicon to match /favicon.ico ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews). Try to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: I tried this and it makes no diffrence..

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /reurl.se/trunk/main/public_html/

Options -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)$ index.php?reurl=$1

Comment: @plweb.se: So there are no further rules than the one you’ve posted?

Comment: The "Options -MultiViews" worked on the apache server my hosting company is using 1.3.41 with the changes made to .htaccess file. But it did not work my own computer that's is running apache 2.2. I had to removed MultiViews option at apache2.conf.